# What's the difference between onClick ={ () => function()} and onClick = {function()}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What's the difference between this code:

```
<button onClick={()=>props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)}>Submit</button>
```

and

```
<button onClick={props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)}>Submit</button>
```

The difference is the first one has the parentheses and the second one doesn't. Without the parentheses, my app seems to be re-render indefinitely. Can someone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: The different is in first it is not executing the function , it is calling the function . In second , it is executing the function  there only.

Comment: At `onClick` you should not call the function, instead set a function reference. In the first case you write another function inside the `onClick` which returns a function reference and the second case you call the function directly. Which means your `submitHandler` function executes before clicking the button. It doesn't wait for the click event.

Comment: An `onClick` event handler is a function, so that prop is expecting a function, so unless `props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)` is returning a function, the second line of code is invalid.

Comment: First example is calling the function and second is executing. Depending on what you do in the submit handler this could cause the indefinite re-rendering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In first one:

```
<button onClick={()=>props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)}>Submit</button>
```

This is arrow function and it will trigger only onClick of the button.

In second one:

```
<button onClick={props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)}>Submit</button>
```

This is a normal function call , which calls the method as soon the rendering of the component happens.

Answer (score 8):

The first creates a function that calls `submitHandler` with an argument and assigns that function to `onClick`.

The second **immediately** (i.e. during the render step) calls `submitHandler` with an argument and assigns **the return value** to `onClick`.

Comment: So what you are saying is even if the function is wrapped inside the onClick event, it will execute none the less?

Comment: Functions assigned to `onClick` get called when the click event is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the fact that a function is assigned to `onClick` via {} doesn't mean that it will be triggered on html user request. The {} is a compile time action.

Another words:
`onClick=>` {execute what is here at compile time and assign the result into `onClick` action}

If you have a `props.submitHandler()` function call inside {} it will be executed and return value assigned to onClick.

If you have a `()=>props.submitHandler` it is an **arrow function** and its execution will be "binded" to onClick user action. Traditional method of doin' it (without using fancy arrow functions) would be

```
<button onClick={function(){props.submitHandler(searchInputValue)}}>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first one  arrow function returns back a function which is assigned to the onClick

In the second one we call the function when the component renders hence it's not assigned to the onClick handler of the button as function pointer is not returned in the second case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).