# onClick event firing off after render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, sidebar

I have a sidebar menu in react, when buttons are clicked in this sidebar I want to update state of a variable. However the event fires off on render instead of waiting for a click, help much appreciated!

Side Bar

```
return (
        <>
        <div id="container1">
            <ProSidebar id='tester1'>
                <SidebarHeader>
                    <h1>Header Title</h1>
                    
                </SidebarHeader>

                <SidebarContent>
                    <Menu iconShape="square">
                              
                        <MenuItem onClick={funx(1)} icon={<FiHome className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem icon={<FaList className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem icon={<FaRegHeart className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem icon={<RiPencilLine className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem icon={<BiCog className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>

                    </Menu>
                </SidebarContent>

                <SidebarFooter>
                    <Menu iconShape="square">
                        <MenuItem icon={<FiLogOut />}>{x}</MenuItem>
                     </Menu>
                </SidebarFooter>
            </ProSidebar>
        </div>
        </>
    );
```

And where the state gets set:

```
const [x, setX] = useState([]);

    const funx = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        setX(e);
        
    }
```

I'd like to add if I remove the `e` parameter from `funx`, and only call `funx` in my menu, the onclick event seems to be working fine. However I want to pass 1/2/3/etc. depending on what's clicked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between onClick ={ () => function()} and onClick = {function()}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930655/whats-the-difference-between-onclick-function-and-onclick-functi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onClick={funx(1)}` the code inside the brackets is evaluated at render, so you're actually calling the function. You want to pass a function reference. If you need to pass the `1` you could do:

```
 <MenuItem onClick={() => funx(1)} ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the onClick event handler function like  `<MenuItem onClick={funx(1)} icon={<FiHome className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>`

You have to change the as like code given below:

```
 <MenuItem onClick={() => funx(1)} icon={<FiHome className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
```

Or you can modify the event handler function as shown below:

```
const funx = (value) = (event) => {
    console.log(value);
    setX(value);
}
```

Now you can call the function as below:

```
<MenuItem onClick={funx(1)} icon={<FiHome className='sideBarIcon'/>}></MenuItem>
```