# How send Event state to child of child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, nested, components, state

I want to `console.log` on click of button in child of child, but console is logged on page reload and does not work for `onClick`, how can I fix this?

Parent.jsx :

```
import Child from "./child";

const Parent = () => {
  const alertHandler = (id) => {
    // alert("Hello: " + id);
    console.log("Hello world: " + id);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      This is PARENT :
      <Child alHandler={alertHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Child:

```
import ChildOfChild from "./ChildOfChild";

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      This is child
      <ChildOfChild alHandler={props.alHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Child Of Child:

```
const ChildOfChild = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child Of Child
      <br />
      <button onClick={props.alHandler(5)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildOfChild;
```

Comment: Did you try to write
<button onClick={() =>props.alHandler(5)}>Click</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const ChildOfChild = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        Child Of Child
        <br />
        <button
        //onClick={props.alHandler(5)}  <---this is called during rendering

        //↓this is called only when u click it
          onClick={() => {        
            props.alHandler(5);    
          }}  
        > 
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default ChildOfChild;
```

[image: Edit Child of child]

[What's the difference between onClick ={ () => function()} and onClick = {function()}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930655/whats-the-difference-between-onclick-function-and-onclick-functi)

Answer (score 1):

try this please.

```
const ChildOfChild = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child Of Child
      <br />
      <button onClick={(e) => {        
            props.alHandler(5);    
          }>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildOfChild;
```