# useState Inside Async Function Throws TypeError

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to trigger a Button's loading state while waiting for API calls.
This is my code below:

```
export default function JobAddPage() {
    
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    async function handleSubmit() {
           setLoading(true);
           try {
                // API Calls
           } catch (error) {...}         
           setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <LoadingButton loading={loading} onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</LoadingButton>
    );
}
```

The Code works but when I add the `setLoading` hook inside `handleSubmit` then I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'state')
```

Are you not allowed to have useState hooks inside async functions in React?
I've read this article: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

I can get this code to work on class components, it seems fairly simple.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your LoadingButton component?

Comment: Its from Material UI: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/loading-button/#main-content

Answer (score 1):

This is probably how you're loading the form itself. What I would suggest trying is this:

Change your onClick event to:

```
onClick{() => handleSubmit()}
```

You may console log your value to see what is going on.

Comment: This is a good link on why an arrow function may help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930655/whats-the-difference-between-onclick-function-and-onclick-functi).

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine.  But is is clear this is not the ACTUAL CODE.  Can you post the missing parts?  Include all your `imports` as well as the full contents of the async method.

My *guess* is that the `useState` method you are calling is *not* the `useState` exported from React.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you should put your `setLoading(true)` inside the `try` block